# Run client applications from VMWare Workstation Host

Tags: vmware-workstation

Does anyone know how to run applications hosted on a client VM from an icon created on the host computer?

For example I want to run IE8 installed on the client VM on my host XP computer running IE6. I cant update to IE6 on the host because of compliance issues.  I'm trying to do this with VMWare Workstation 7.

Comment: Easy with *nix-to-*nix (except OS X as remote), trickier with *nix-to-Windows, awful otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  Not sure it counts as a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean fully integrated in the host environnement, you would install at first wmare tools and place you guest system in unity mode (i think it is called like that).
i've done this using vmware workstation on Linux with Windows Guest system

Comment: Thank you for your help.  This should work.  I'm trying it out now.

Comment: Do you know if the util "vmware-unity-helper.exe" works in Windows?  I found post that say that it only works with linux but that was for version 6.5 and I'm running 7.  I'm not sure if it's now supported in 7 though.  Thanks again.